# When I mention a webinar's title in an article, do I italicize it?

Tags: titles

I'm writing a review on a webinar that was recently done. In my article, do I italicize the title of the webinar, or do I put it in quotations or underline it? Google search just shows bibliography guidelines, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I believe this is a matter of taste. Whichever style you use, it is important to use it consistently within your review.